# Extracting data via API in Superset 1.5.2

Tags: apache-superset

I am running superset version 1.5.2. Using the API i want to get some data out via SQL. Unfortunately following this documentation https://superset.apache.org/docs/api/. I think the sqllab api is not yet implemented in this version. Does anyone know how to extract data from superset via API in the older superset version?